# How can I use org.jetbrains.anko.startActivity to optimize startActivity function?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I have read the article https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Intents.

I can use `startActivity(intentFor<SomeOtherActivity>("id" to 5).singleTop())` to open  a new Activity.

The Code A is converted from Java by Android Studio 3.0.1 automatically. I can invoke it with `openActivity(applicationContext, UIBuy::class.java)`.

How can I use `org.jetbrains.anko.startActivity` to optimize the function? Thanks!

BTW, the Code B is wrong!

**Code A**

```
fun openActivity(mContext: Context, myClass: Class<*>) {
    val intent = Intent().setClass(mContext, myClass)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

    mContext.startActivity(intent)
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun openActivity(mContext: Context, myClass: Class<*>) {   
    startActivity<myClass>().FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For optimalization you can use this code:

```
startActivity(intentFor<YourActivity>().newTask())
```

Where intentFor is function from Anko.

The problem with startActivity() from Anko is that it doesn't let you set flags. You can only pass params to be placed inside Bundle. This is the implementation of this function:

```
inline fun <reified T: Activity> Context.startActivity(vararg params: Pair<String, Any?>) =
        AnkoInternals.internalStartActivity(this, T::class.java, params)
```

And internalStartActivity uses internally createIntent method populated with "params". So as you can see you have to provide Intent by yourself.

EDIT:

To create openActivity method you can use inline method to let you use class generics.

As it was mentioned in comments there are different ways of passing context:

(extension function of Context)

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity>Context.openActivity() {
    startActivity(intentFor<T>().newTask())
}
```

or
(pass context as parameter)

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity>openActivity(context: Context) {
    context.startActivity(intentFor<T>().newTask())
}
```

or
(use inside parent Activity if you have such)

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity>openActivity() {
    startActivity(intentFor<T>().newTask())
}
```

[Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) you will find more about inline functions and reified type parameters. But as you can see - suggested solution is very similar to original Anko methods.

Comment: You cannot use the extension function `intentFor<>` inside the function `openActivity` because you don't know the type (unless you modify `openActivity` with generics). I supposed @hellocw wanted to extract the code into a function to avoid calling `newTask()` every time.

Comment: See my edited answer. I also realized that @hellocw wanted to extract it as a function. You can easly do this using reifield. That's really nice feature of Kotlin

Comment: OK. But you need a `Context` to be able to call `startActivity`. You may convert your function into an extension function with `Context.openActivity`.

Comment: @JavierSA I've edited my answer to show different methods of passing context. I think it's a little bit redundant but maybe someone will make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *Code B* (`startActivity<myClass>()`) doesn't compile because you can't write a `Class` object as the name of a type for a generic.

**You can't** use `org.jetbrains.anko.startActivity` if you want to set flags to your Intent. Why? If you inspect the file `Intents.kt` of `anko-commons-0.10.4-sources.jar`, you'll see that the function extensions `startActivity` only accept `Pair`s, which are the names and values you want to put as extras in your Intent.

However, you can simplify your code if you use the extension function `org.jetbrains.anko.newTask`, that is sugar syntax for `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`:

```
fun openActivity(mContext: Context, myClass: Class<*>) =
    mContext.startActivity(Intent().setClass(mContext, myClass).newTask())
```

Then, you can do `openActivity(applicationContext, UIBuy::class.java)`.

Answer (score 0):

I do that:

```
application.intentFor<AuthActivity>()
                .clearTop()
                .newTask()
                .also(application::startActivity)
```